# Microsoft Cluster: The volume 'ClusterPerformanceHistory' is running low on available storage capacity

Tags: windows-cluster

Not finding anything in documentation. Since some months ago, I regualrly have the volume ClusterPerformanceHistory (which is automatically created with around 12gb net size) running full, with in result charting stopping to work.

There seems to be no indication as why, there are no events. The health service is running. There seems to be no powershell command to clean this up, all  Ican do is stop the health service, nuke the volume and restart it so it gets recreated.

Any better way to maintain this? In the past - this was auto cleaning and i did not have to look at it for months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself: There is nothing to be done here except manually making a new volume and MAKING IT LARGER.

https://blog.mpecsinc.com/2020/02/21/s2d-ashci-extend-the-cluster-performance-history-cluster-disk/ has a powershell script for this and explanations...

```
$ClVDToExtend = "Cluster Virtual Disk (ClusterPerformanceHistory)"
# Virtual Disk Name
$VDToExtend = "ClusterPerformanceHistory"
# Size to Extend to
$VDNewSize = 67GB
$VDPartitionSize = 66.5GB
# Suspend the Disk
Suspend-ClusterResource -Name $ClVDToExtend
# Extend - No Storage Tiers
Get-VirtualDisk $VDtoExtend | Resize-VirtualDisk -Size "$($VDNewSize)" # Final size
# Get its partition
Get-VirtualDisk $VDtoExtend | Get-Disk | Get-Partition
$Partition = Get-VirtualDisk $VDtoExtend | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Where-Object PartitionNumber -Eq 2
$Partition
# Extend that partition
$Partition | Resize-Partition -Size "$($VDPartitionSize)"
# Resume the Disk
Resume-ClusterResource -Name $ClVDToExtend
```

MS basically did the sizing wrong here so that the usual cleanup scripts are not cleaning up enough ;)